# Usage of user ID as primary key in a large table

Tags: mysql, optimization, key, primary-key, innodb

I have a table (id (PK, UNIQUE), user_id, [other columns here]) with a large amount (100k+) of users' orders, where each user can access only orders that have set user_id of him.

I wonder how using user_id as primary key could affect performance of SELECT queries on this database. Is there any efficient solution to maintain large amount of rows binded to users (each order have one owner) in a single InnoDB table?

Comment: `User_id` might be a bad primary key for a table where there is more than one entry for each `user_id`.

Comment: @Solarflare *Might*?

Comment: @philipxy well, "might" was meant as a "you might want to rethink that". He can still use a composite primary key with `user_id` as first column to create his physical order. But to give an assessment @pfcode (without knowing more about the data/database/queries, and without going into the details for the reasons and the benefits and consequences e.g. to inserts, other queries or index sizes): you usually don't need to think about that. Your (order) id seems to be the logical primary key in your table. Focus your optimization on good indexes, indexes are the most relevant performance factor.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks. What I meant was, as I wrote on an answer below, user_id *cannot be* a primary key for a table where there is more than one entry for each user_id.

Comment: @philipxy Yes, I am of course aware of that, but thanks for the clarification in case someone (else) misunderstood my comment, you are right it wasn't perfectly clear what I wanted to express there.

Answer (score 1):

If most queries include a specific value for `user_id`, this is more efficient:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, id),  -- to get the benefit of 'clustering' around user_id
INDEX(id)  -- to make AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data type of the two are the same, i.e. `int` or `uint`, it does not make any different in terms of performance.

You can safely drop ID and make UID the primary key.

Comment: user_id cannot be a primary key because it is not unique; a user can have more than one order.

Answer (score 0):

The table is "of users' orders". If the user_id plus certain columns uniquely identify an order and no subset of those does then that set of columns is a candidate key (to be declared as PK/UNIQUE). If there is no set of columns uniquely identifying an order then you need to use a surrogate like id. (You might want it for other reasons.)

Since there can be more than one order per user, {user_id} is *not* a candidate key of this table.